# Cannot find nested package

Tags: go, gopath, go-packages

I have a project with the following structure:

```
myapp/
  -services/
     -services/
         -exch.go
     -services.go
  -server.go
```

Having $GOPATH set to `/home/dev/dev/go`
this is how `server.go` names it's package and imports:

```
//server.go
package main

import (
  "net/http"
  "github.com/labstack/echo"
  "myapp/services"
)
```

this is `services.go`:

```
//services.go
package services

import (
  "fmt"
  "myapp/services/exch"
)
```

and this is `exch.go`:

```
//exch.go
package exch

import (
  "net/http"
  "fmt"
  "io/ioutil"
  "encoding/json
)
```

Now, `server.go` imports `package services` fine, but `services.go` cannot find `package exch`. I tried changing the imports path several ways but cannot make it work. Am I missing something?

Might be useful to know that /myapp is located here: /home/dev/dev/go/src

Comment: One directory per package, one package per directory. If `exch.go` is supposed to be in package `services/exch`, it needs to be in a directory `services/exch`, not in directory `services/services`.

Comment: that was it @Adrian. Thanks. If you want to add it as an answer i mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One directory per package, one package per directory. If exch.go is supposed to be imported as `services/exch`, it needs to be in a directory `services/exch`, not in directory `services/services`.